# Linking with .dylib library from the command line using clang

Tags: c, macos, clang, dylib

I'm trying to write a C program using a library. The library has provided a `include/` and `lib/` directory with header files and `.dylib` files, respectively.

My file is in the same directory as `include/` and `lib/`. I'm trying to compile it with the following command:

```
clang -I"./include/" -L"./lib/" -lcsfml-graphics -lcsfml-window test.c
```

However, when I go to run my program, I get the following error:

```
% ./a.out 
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib
  Referenced from: ~/src/CSFML-2.4-osx-clang/./a.out
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      ./a.out
```

What is the correct way to compile using these libraries? I'd prefer to simply use the command line as I'm writing a small program, without having to set up Xcode, etc.

```
% ls -l lib/
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1  staff   50296 Mar  1  2017 libcsfml-audio.2.4.0.dylib*
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1  staff      26 Mar  1  2017 libcsfml-audio.2.4.dylib@ -> libcsfml-audio.2.4.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1  staff      24 Mar  1  2017 libcsfml-audio.dylib@ -> libcsfml-audio.2.4.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1  staff  163680 Mar  1  2017 libcsfml-graphics.2.4.0.dylib*
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1  staff      29 Mar  1  2017 libcsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib@ -> libcsfml-graphics.2.4.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1  staff      27 Mar  1  2017 libcsfml-graphics.dylib@ -> libcsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1  staff   67272 Mar  1  2017 libcsfml-network.2.4.0.dylib*
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1  staff      28 Mar  1  2017 libcsfml-network.2.4.dylib@ -> libcsfml-network.2.4.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1  staff      26 Mar  1  2017 libcsfml-network.dylib@ -> libcsfml-network.2.4.dylib
```

Comment: Show the output from `ls -l lib`. I suspect that you have a broken symlink in that directory.

Comment: @KenThomases added

Comment: Can't be closed because of the bounty but it's a straight dupe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464149/linking-is-jacked-up-what-is-rpath-macos-x and probably many others.

Comment: @n.m. none of those contain a command line answer, at least not that I can figure out

Comment: They do. `-Wl,-rpath` etc.

Comment: @n.m. I have tried that, `clang -I"./include/" -L"./lib/" -lcsfml-graphics -lcsfml-window -Wl,-rpath,"@executable_path/lib" test.c` and those don't work either

Comment: This should work. Ask a separate question about this with as much details as you can. Also try specifying an absolute path to the libraries folder instead of @executable_path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that after fixing rpath with `clang -I"./include/" -L"./lib/" -lcsfml-graphics -lcsfml-window -Wl,-rpath,"@executable_path/lib" test.c` you're still missing SFML libraries. I've just checked that CSFML depends on SFML, and based on your `ls -l lib/` listing, SFML is clearly absent in lib/. My guess is that after fixing rpath you may not have noticed that the absent dependency has changed to `@rpath/libsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib` instead of `@rpath/libcsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib`. Please, download SFML libraries and put them into lib/.

Now to your question, how to build on macOS from the command line. Your building steps are correct, so I suppose the difficult part is how the dependencies are searched by dyld, not how they're linked with ld.

### A short theory.

There are 4 ways a binary (an executable or a dynamic library) references its dependencies:

- by an absolute or relative path (the latter is relative to your working directory);
- by @executable_path, expanding to the path of the executable which is the root of the dependency tree (in case you have recursive dependencies);
- by @loader_path, expanding to the path of the executable or a library for which the dependency is searched, i.e. it's the path of the direct parent in the dependency tree;
- by @rpath, which is substituted in turn by each rpath found in your binary, and this is the most flexible way as you can search in several directories by having multiple rpaths.

Now the question is how to ensure the dependencies are correctly referenced. As @mattmilten pointed out, there are 2 methods for that:

- make your build system/build script/manual build commands ensure the references are correct;
- use install_name_tool to correct the broken references.

### Making it automatic during the build.

In order for the first method to work you need to make sure the *identification names* of the dependency libraries are correct. Suppose you're linking a binary against some library `libA.dylib`. The identification name of libA.dylib is the default reference which will be used by the linker (ld) when building your binary. You can find it by looking at the first line of `otool -L libA.dylib` (or alternatively at the LC_ID_DYLIB section of `otool -l libA.dylib`). In case of `libcsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib` it's `@rpath/libcsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib` and it was passed to a.out on linking, that's why you're seeing it in the error message when dyld fails to meet it.

Setting a correct identification name is a responsibility of the libA.dylib authors. It is set according to their expectations as to where libA.dylib could be placed (using @rpath is a good choice) as well as their versioning scheme (in case of CSFML version 2.4.0 could be replaced with 2.4.x without losing binary compatibility). If you're building libA.dylib yourself you can set it with `-install_name` param (e.g. `clang -Wl,-dylib -Wl,-install_name,@executable_path/libA.dylib -o libA.dylib liba.c`). If it's a 3rd party library you can change it with `install_name_tool -id @rpath/libA.dylib libA.dylib`.

Identification name, to the best of my knowledge, is only used during linking and not used when loading a binary, so if you prefer the second method of fixing incorrect references with install_name_tool you can ignore it.

### Manual fixing.

Fixing the references with install_name_tool is simple but tedious. You'll probably need a script when there are a lot of incorrect references. All you need is the following set of commands (the `binary` placeholder should obviously be replaced with an actual binary name):

- `install_name_tool -change @executable_path/libA.dylib @rpath/libA.dylib binary` to change reference `@executable_path/libA.dylib` -> `@rpath/libA.dylib`;
- `install_name_tool -add_rpath @executable_path/lib binary` to add `@executable_path/lib` to rpaths;
- `install_name_tool -delete_rpath @executable_path/lib binary` to remove `@executable_path/lib` from rpaths;
- `otool -l binary` to check existing rpaths (just look at the LC_RPATH sections).

Comment: Hi @miadz, thank you so much - I was completely unaware that CSFML needs SFML as a dependency. This fixed the issue completely

Comment: @JoethePerson I'm glad the problem is resolved :) Actually, `otool -L` is one of the most helpful commands when inspecting unmet dependencies, when run on `libcsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib` it will show you that CSFML also depends on SFML, in fact CSFML is a thin wrapper over SFML. And thx for the bounty, btw.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the environment variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. It should contain the path to `libcsfml-graphics.2.4.dylib`. Another solution might be to add this path to your `PATH` variable.

You can inspect the paths of your binary with `otool -L` and modify them with `install_name_tool -change`. Ideally, though, you should build your binary to contain the correct rpath to its dependencies using `-R` when linking/compiling.

Comment: I'm a little uncertain on how to use install_name_tool, I've tried `install_name_tool -add_path "@executable_path/lib/" a.out` but that gives the error: `more than one input file specified (@executable_path/lib/ and -add_path)`. What is the correct syntax of this command?

Comment: Have a look here https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/install_name_tool/ Just try a few things, you can always rebuild the library if you mess up, right?

Comment: I did try reading the manual, and there aren't any examples of how to invoke the command

Comment: How about `install_name_tool -change "libcsfml-graphics.dylib" "@executable_path/lib/libcsfml-graphics.dylib" a.out`?